# latest python 3 not compatible in ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-18.04, python-3.8

I installed python 3.8.4 in ubuntu 18.04 but still the

```sh
python3 --version
```

shows the version as 3.6.9

The python3.8.4 I installed was installed as `python3.8` it did not replace the existing python3

how to do so?

Comment: You should look into your `path`, try typing `which python3` to see which binary is being used. It's possible to have several `python3` installations. Depending on how you install it, and what is in your current path - different binaries will be used. if you type `echo $PATH` you'll see where it's looking for `python3` binaries - the first place it find it - it uses that one!

Comment: You can also list all python installation `ls -ls /usr/bin/python*`

Comment: @avloss the path of python 3.8 is snaps folder, i installed it using snap, can i change my system to call python 3.8 from snaps when i give comand python3?

Comment: @dejdej ,i realised python3.8 wasnt in that folder as i installed it using snaps, sudo apt install python3 installs python 3.6.9 and does not install later version, or does it?

Comment: just specify full path to the python that you want to be running

Comment: @avloss but that would work in terminal, i wanted to set the interpreter of my pycharm to be python 3.8 but i cannot find it nor does the pycharm detect it

Comment: go to "Preferences -> Project Interpreter" -- you can pick which python to use for any given project.

Comment: @avloss i tried doing that, but i cannot find python3.8 file, i tried ```echo $PATH python3.8``` but i cannot find the python3.8 .exe file that is required by the pycharm. btw thank you for helping on this trivia.